# Como capitalizar nomes em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, capitalização

Tenho em minha aplicação nomes próprios em maiúsculo, por exemplo: "JOSÉ DA SILVA".

Gostaria de formatar da seguinte maneira: "José da Silva". Como fazer?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Uma maneira é utilizando método [ToTitleCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) para capitalizar palavras em C#.

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase("JOSÉ DA SILVA".ToLower()); // retorna "José Da Silva"
```

A chamada `ToLower` é necessário pois o método `ToTitleCase` não capitaliza palavras todas em maiúsculo (ele considera que são acrônimos).

O problema é que a palavra "Da" também foi capitalizada. Para esses casos segue um método simples que desconsidera certas palavras excepcionais:

```
static string CapitalizarNome(string nome)
{
    string[] excecoes = new string[] { "e", "de", "da", "das", "do", "dos" };
    var palavras = new Queue<string>();
    foreach (var palavra in nome.Split(' '))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(palavra))
        {
            var emMinusculo = palavra.ToLower();
            var letras = emMinusculo.ToCharArray();
            if (!excecoes.Contains(emMinusculo)) letras[0] = char.ToUpper(letras[0]);
            palavras.Enqueue(new string(letras));
        }
    }
    return string.Join(" ", palavras);
}
```

Comment: Eu só adicionaria as palavras "e", "das", "dos".

Comment: @AugustoMen feito :)

Comment: E eu transformaria em *extension method*, mas isso não é o mais importante ;)

Answer (score 3):

Eu poderia sugerir [algo pronto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), mas surpreendentemente se estiver tudo um minúsculo ele não faz a capitalização e precisaria fazer outra operação antes, o que deixaria bem ineficiente, como são as respostas postadas, o que me motivou postar outra resposta porque se tiver que fazer essa operação muitas vezes a ineficiência é um preço alto a se pagar.

Olhado o fonte do método pronto também se vê muita ineficiência, ainda que por ter que funcionar em todos os contextos seja um pouco justificável. De qualquer forma quase sempre a pessoa precisa só em um contexto, e as respostas aqui só se preocupam com um.

Note que eu preferi dar um *trim* para fazer o mesmo que as outras respostas, mesmo que a pergunta não peça isto, mas uma pequena alteração poderia ser feita, até mesmo regulada por um parâmetro. Também fiz outras questões se resolverem igual as respostas dadas, mesmo sem critério na pergunta.

O código fica um pouco mais complexo por causa das exceções, porém mais eficiente, por não fazer alocações e pressionar o GC:

```
using System.Text;
                    
System.Console.WriteLine("|" + Capitalizar("   JOSÉ   DA COSTA DOS PEREIRAS E SILVA   ") + "|");

static string Capitalizar(string texto) {
    StringBuilder novo = new(texto.Length);
    for (var i = 0; i < texto.Length; i++) {
        var atual = char.ToLower(texto[i]);
        var anterior = i == 0 ? ' ' : char.ToLower(texto[i - 1]);
        var proximo = i > texto.Length - 2 ? 0 : char.ToLower(texto[i + 1]);
        var segundo = i > texto.Length - 3 ? 0 : char.ToLower(texto[i + 2]);
        var terceiro = i > texto.Length - 4 ? 0 : char.ToLower(texto[i + 3]);
        if (atual == ' ' && anterior == ' ') continue;
        if (anterior != ' ' ||
            (atual == 'e' && proximo == ' ') ||
            (atual == 'd' &&
            ((proximo == 'a' || proximo == 'e' || proximo == 'o') && (segundo == ' ')) ||
            ((proximo == 'a' || proximo == 'o') && (segundo == 's') && (terceiro == ' '))
            )) novo.Append(atual);
        else novo.Append(char.ToUpper(atual));
    }
    if (novo[novo.Length - 1] == ' ') novo.Remove(novo.Length - 1, 1);
    return novo.ToString();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/1hcKDm). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vdimRh). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Capitalize2.cs).

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma bem simples de fazer isso é usando `Regex.Replace` e substituir todas as palavras por suas versões title-case, exceto em alguns casos especiais, que serão colocados em um dicionário de normalização:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = Regex.Replace("dia dos pais", @"\b(\w)(\w*)\b", TitleCase);
}

// dicionário de normalização, com chaves que são case-insensitive
static readonly Dictionary<string, string> special
    = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    {
        { "e", "e" },
        { "de", "de" },
        { "da", "da" },
        { "do", "do" },
        { "das", "das" },
        { "dos", "dos" },
    };

static string TitleCase(Match matchPalavra)
{
    // se for uma das palavras especiais
    string replacement;
    if (special.TryGetValue(matchPalavra.Value, out replacement))
        return replacement;

    // se não for uma palavra especial, faz title-case
    return matchPalavra.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper()
         + matchPalavra.Groups[2].Value.ToLower();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As convenções são mais ou menos consensuais, e podem ser expressas de forma mais universal como *regular expression*. Passo-a-passo da normalização de um nome próprio de pessoa física:

1. `ToTitleCase(nome)`, iniciais maíusculas, que também pode ser referido como `InitCap()` em outras linguagens ou frameworks.
2. Por segurança um `trim()`  ou melhor ainda um *trim* depois de substituir todos os espaços múltiplos ou exóticos pelo espaço padrão singular, ou seja, a *regex* `/\s+/gu` por espaço.
3. Não nos esqueçamos do júnior, que a rigor precisa ser grafado também com inicial maiúscula e por extenso. Portanto: substituir `/ (?:jr\.?|j[uú]nior)$/i` por `" Júnior"`.
4. O "e" sozinho, substituir todos os `" E "` por `" e "`.
5. As demais preposições, `/ (d)([eao]|[ao]s) /gi` por `" d\2 "`.

Answer (score -2):

Aqui está outra solução fazendo uso do **Regex.Replace**, com um código menor:

```
public static string CapitalizarNomeProprio(this string nome)
{
    string nomeProprio = new CultureInfo("pt-BR", false).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(nome.ToLower());
    var excecoes = new string[] { "E", "De", "Da", "Das", "Do", "Dos" };
    nomeProprio = Regex.Replace(nomeProprio, @"(\w+)", m => (excecoes.Contains(m.Value) ? m.Value.ToLower() : m.Value));
    return nomeProprio;
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).