# Transformar a primeira letra de uma string em maiúscula?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Exemplo:

Tenho uma *string*  `"stack exchange"`, como faço para transformar seu primeiro caractere, ficando `"Stack exchange"`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

É isto:

```
var texto = "stack exchange";
var upper = char.ToUpper(texto[0]) + texto.Substring(1);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Y0YLJz). E [no **repl.it**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BODLgp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Capitalize.cs).

- [`Char.ToUpper()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.toupper?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Char_ToUpper_System_Char_)
- [`Substring()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_)

Tem maneiras melhores de resolver a questão mas que estão fora do requisito da pergunta. Se interessar já tem uma [pergunta sobre o assunto aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/247/101).

Esta forma é mais legível para a maioria dos programadores do que usando LINQ. É óbvio para qualquer pessoa o que o algoritmo faz. Não precisa adicionar um *namespace* extra para executá-lo. Legibilidade é subjetiva mas tamanho não é e este é mais curto. Ele usa menos métodos. Claro que pode-se argumentar que também usa 2 operadores e que no fundo eles são métodos, mas C# não é Java. Se os operadores são métodos, é detalhe de implementação e não se pode argumentar sobre expressividade ignorando isto. Eu acho mais expressivo usar operadores do que métodos. Tem que ache o contrário, Então isto é subjetivo. Cada um escolhe o que é melhor para si.

Além disto este é, por acaso, mais rápido. Eu sempre defendo em minhas respostas que não se deve fazer otimização prematura, que não se deve perseguir ganhos de performance inúteis. Mas nem sempre é óbvio o que é útil ou não. Se você vai por este algoritmo em um método que tem potencial de ser usado dentro de laços longos, o ganho passa ser importante. Se não fosse assim, os métodos da BCL não precisariam ser tão otimizados como são. Nem estou pregando a otimização pela otimização, mas se tem uma forma simples de fazer como esta, se ela não tem nenhum desvantagem real (ser idiomático é questionável, até porque ninguém disse que programar de forma declarativa ou funcional é o certo em C#, é apenas uma opção, além disto ser idiomático tem que trazer vantagens claras, quando isto não acontece, é bobagem perseguir ideais, seria algo prematuro). Em alguns cenários [a diferença não é nada desprezível](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OweU7Y).

Answer (score 7):

Dica do [SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4405876/2387977), pequeno método para fazer isto:

```
public static string FirstCharToUpper(string input)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        throw new ArgumentException("Insira uma palavra diferente de nula ou vazia");
    return input.First().ToString().ToUpper() + input.Substring(1);
}
```

Você também pode se interessar por [outra transformação](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4135491/2387977), a *Title Case* (conhecida também como *Capitalize*). Ela transforma "stack exchange" para "**S**tack **E**xchange":

```
public string ToTitleCase(string str)
{
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(str.ToLower());
}
```

Comment: Tem um pessoal com uma mania de usar LINQ para fazer coisas simples.

Comment: Pessoalmente, acho mais elegante :)

Comment: Exigir incluir um *namespace* à toa, ter pior performance, fazer 4 chamadas de métodos, a maioria das pessoas não entendem o que a linha faz de fato e chega até ser mais longo. Eu acho extramente deselegante.

Comment: Eu acho mais fácil/natural de ler, então para mim vale o _trade-off_ de facilidade de leitura pela performance que, convenhamos, vai ser imperceptível na grande maioria dos casos. Mas, como eu disse, é pessoal.

Comment: @bigown Creio que, em termos de performance, `First` e `[0]` sejam *muito* semelhantes. A diferença de perf é desprezável, e decidir o estilo de código baseado nessa pequena diferença é [optimização prematura](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/80092/101308). Além disso, tenho 100% de certeza que o bottleneck da aplicação não vai ser a chamada a `First`.

Comment: Fora isso, a solução é equivalente à sua, em termos de quantidade de invocações de métodos/operações. Envolve obter o primeiro caractér (`First` vs `[0]`), converter para maiusculo (`ToUpper`), e conversão do caractér para string (chamada explícita a `ToString` vs conversor implícito). Quanto a expressividade - nem sempre "mais curto" significa "mais fácil de ler". Basta ir ao [CodeGolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), onde o objectivo é tornar o código mais curto possível, e por vezes fica indecifrável. No entanto, neste caso em particular, acho que ambas as soluções são expressivas.

Comment: @dcastro performance é um ponto apenas e se for quase a mesma coisa, eu vou sempre no que é mais rápido. Mas neste caso, só tem desvantagens em utilizar o LINQ. Otimização prematura é outra coisa. Isto é fazer o mais simples que por acaso é o mais rápido. LINQ não é simples, ele deve ser evitado se não trouxer alguma vantagem. Neste caso não traz. Vou repetir algo que você perdeu já que você acha LINQ fácil de ler porque VOCÊ lê bem ele. Quase ninguém entende essa linha de código. A maioria dos programadores usam isto como receita de bolo e não como algo que ele sabe o que é isto.

Comment: @bigown Num contexto geral, eu sou completamente a favor do uso de LINQ. Quanto á legibilidade de LINQ, e ao facto dos programadores nao-experientes nao perceberem de imediato, eu recomendo este artigo do Mark Seemann: [Idiomatic or idiosyncratic?](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/08/03/idiomatic-or-idiosyncratic/). O facto de programadores nao experientes ainda nao estarem familiarizados com o idioma, nao é razao para nao o usar. É razão para o aprenderem.

Comment: O mesmo acontece com qualquer tecnologia: se o desconhecimento de uma tecnologia nova fosse razao para nao a usar, ainda estavamos todos a programar em C, com CPUs single-core.

Comment: Mas isso é uma coisa sua, você faça como quiser, mas não imponha isso para todo mundo. Eu uso o LINQ onde ele traz vantagem, mas não em casos assim, ele não traz nem uma só vantagem. Isto é torre de marfim. O artigo mostra o ponto dele, não uma verdade inexorável. Eu nunca vou trocar ou incentivar um código perfeitamente legível por todos por um que alguns acham melhor e não traz nenhuma vantagem real. Eu sou pragmático, não me apego à conceitos, tecnologias, melhores práticas ou coisa do tipo, eu uso o que é mais simples, o mais simples sempre é mais vitorioso.Por isto há casos de uso do LINQ

Answer (score 0):

Você pode inserir as funcionalidades das respostas anteriores em uma classe static e acessá-lo de qualquer lugar.

**Implementação:**

```
public static class StringExtends
{
   public static string FirstCharToUpper(this string input)
   {
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
         throw new ArgumentException("Insira uma palavra diferente de nula ou vazia");
      return input.Length > 1 ? char.ToUpper(input[0]) + input.Substring(1) : input.ToUpper();
   }
}
```

**Utilização:**

```
var texto = "stack exchange";
var upper = texto.FirstCharToUpper();
```

[exemplo|.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wUnJyt)